# RegEx, Get first symbol "&" in String

Tags: regex

I have string :

```
/url?q=http://www.bbc.com/indonesia/berita_indonesia&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjhqsr6h73OAhVDu48KHTR1AKsQFghDMAs&usg=AFQjCNEv3lNjzDNxPjfpqOtOb0ApNzvCCA
```

I want to get the result like this :

```
http://www.bbc.com/indonesia/berita_indonesia
```

How can I do with using RegEx ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first capturing group of the following expression will extract the part you want. `\?q=([^&]+)`

Comment: thanks for answer. nice it solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it with following regex:

```
/(http:\/\/.+)/
```

the first (and only) capturing group contains value of url.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/xL1rK0/1) you can see it in action and adjust for your prefferred language.

EDIT: this pattern will capture whole URL along with following query string. Do you need url with path and without query string?

Comment: I think OP waiting for smth like [this](https://regex101.com/r/xL1rK0/3).